# Swift 3: What's the safest way to unwrap optional values coming from an array?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

First, I initialize the variables to hold the stock data

```
var applePrice: String?
var googlePrice: String?
var twitterPrice: String?
var teslaPrice: String?
var samsungPrice: String?
var stockPrices = [String]()
```

I fetch current stock prices from YQL, and put those values into an array

```
func stockFetcher() {

    Alamofire.request(stockUrl).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
        if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
            let json = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
            if let applePrice = json["query"]["results"]["quote"][0]["Ask"].string {
                print(applePrice)
                self.applePrice = applePrice
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            if let googlePrice = json["query"]["results"]["quote"][1]["Ask"].string {
                print(googlePrice)
                self.googlePrice = googlePrice
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            if let twitterPrice = json["query"]["results"]["quote"][2]["Ask"].string {
                print(twitterPrice)
                self.twitterPrice = twitterPrice
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            if let teslaPrice = json["query"]["results"]["quote"][3]["Ask"].string {
                print(teslaPrice)
                self.teslaPrice = teslaPrice
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            if let samsungPrice = json["query"]["results"]["quote"][4]["Ask"].string {
                print(samsungPrice)
                self.samsungPrice = samsungPrice
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            let stockPrices = ["\(self.applePrice)", "\(self.googlePrice)", "\(self.twitterPrice)", "\(self.teslaPrice)", "\(self.samsungPrice)"]
            self.stockPrices = stockPrices
            print(json)
        }
    }
}
```

in cellForRowAt indexPath function I print to the label

```
    if self.stockPrices.count > indexPath.row + 1 {
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Current Stock Price: \(self.stockPrices[indexPath.row])" ?? "Fetching stock prices..."
    } else {
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "No data found"
    }
```

I'm running into the issue of printing Current Stock Price: Optional("stock price"), with the word optional. I gather that this is because I'm giving it an array of optional values, but I sort of have to since I actually don't know if there will be data coming from YQL, one of the 5 stocks might be `nil` while the others have data. From reading other similar questions I can see that the solution would be to unwrap the value with `!`, but I'm not so sure how to implement that solution when it's an array with data that might be `nil`, and not just an Int or something.

How can I safely unwrap here and get rid of the word Optional?

Comment: Don't add use string interpolation to add the data to your array; just add the strings directly (ie `[self.applePrice, self.googlePrice,...]` but Duncan's approach is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off:

Any time you repeat the same block of code multiple times and only increase a value from 0 to some max, it is a code smell. You should think about a different way to handle it.

You should use an array to do this processing.

How about a set of enums for indexes:

```
enum companyIndexes: Int {
  case apple
  case google
  case twitter
  case tesla
  //etc...
}
```

Now you can run through your array with a loop and install your values more cleanly:

```
var stockPrices = [String?]()
Alamofire.request(stockUrl).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
    if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
        let json = JSON(responseData.result.value!)
        let pricesArray = json["query"]["results"]["quote"]
        for aPriceEntry in pricesArray {
           let priceString = aPriceEntry["ask"].string
           stockPrices.append(priceString)
        }
   }
}
```

And to fetch a price from the array:

```
let applePrice = stockPrices[companyIndexes.apple.rawValue]
```

That will result in an optional.

You could use the nil coalescing operator (`??`) to replace a nil value with a string like "No price available.":

```
let applePrice = stockPrices[companyIndexes.apple.rawValue] ?? "No price available"
```

or as shown in the other answer:

```
if let applePrice = stockPrices[companyIndexes.apple.rawValue] {
   //we got a valid price
} else
   //We don't have a price for that entry
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a great answer. I'm pretty new still and have never worked with enums, would you mind expanding on how to implement that part, and where in the code it would go? Also where to put the code to fetch the prices - in the stockPrices function I assume, after the for loop?

Comment: This is Swift 101 stuff. Put the enum definition at the top of your file. If you only need to access the array of prices from a single class, put it inside the definition for that class. If you need to access prices from multiple classes, put it above the definition of your class.

Comment: Put the code I posted inside the completion handler for your `Alamofire.request()` function, just like yours was. It's a cleaner way of dealing with parsing out prices for an array of stocks rather than repeating the same code over and over.

Comment: My post was meant as a general guide about a better way of doing things rather than a finished solution. You'll need to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: I'm just starting with programming in general, this is a practice project, so I definitely appreciate any guidance I can get. I've implemented the code way it should be now, and I'm still getting an error "Type string/json has no subscript members" on the letPriceString = aPriceEntry line

Comment: So you need to cast it to the correct type. You could use `let priceString = (aPriceEntry as! [String:Double])["ask"].string` (I'm not sure what the value of an "ask" is. Since you're using `.string` to convert it to a string I assume it's a numeric type like a Double...)

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this outside of Xcode (so there might be typos), but this kind of logic should work.

```
if self.stockPrices.count > indexPath.row + 1 {
    var txt = "Fetching stock prices..."
    if let price = self.stockPrices[indexPath.row] {
        txt = price
    }
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = txt
} else {
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "No data found"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For safe unwrap use that code:

```
if let currentStockPrice = self.stockPrices[indexPath.row]
{
    // currentStockPrice available there
}
// currentStockPrice unavailable
```

If you need to unwrap multiple variables in one if after another it may lead to unreadable code. In such case use this pattern

```
guard let currentStockPrice = self.stockPrices[indexPath.row]
else
{
    // currentStockPrice is unavailable there
    // must escape via return, continue, break etc.
}
// currentStockPrice is available
```